# JPA - Update childs refrence to parent

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jax-rs, named-query

If I have a Parent like this

```
public class Company implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="COMPANY_ID", updatable = false)
private int companyId;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to User
@OneToMany(mappedBy="company")
private List<User> users;
}
```

And a child like this

```
public class User implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="USER_ID", updatable=false)
private int userId;

private String username;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Company
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="COMPANY_ID")
private Company company;
}
```

And then in my JAX-RS REST call I retrieve a user from the DB that is in Company A and I want to change that user to Company B. Here is what I have

```
@POST
@Path("updateUserCompany")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response updateUserCompany() {

    //this get the company I want to set the user to
    Company company = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Company.getCompanyByName", Company.class)
                .setParameter("companyName", "CompanyB")
                .getSingleResult();

    //this gets the user i want to change
     User user = entityManager.createNamedQuery("User.getUserById", User.class).setParameter("userId", 1).getSingleResult();

     user.setCompany(company);
     entityManager.persist(user);
     entityManager.flush();
```

But the user is not updated in the DB? How can I have it update in the DB?

Thanks

Comment: 1) Is your JAX-RS REST class  EJB? Because if it's not this code performed not inside transaction. Annotate your `updateUserCompany()` method with `javax.transaction.Transactional`. 2) Use `entityManager.merge()` method instead `persist` whish is using for persisting new entities (inserting rows)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to the company not being updated from A to B in the company table, when persist is invoked on the user entity.

Have you tried the cascade property? It is meant for scenarios where the mapped entities(child) need to be saved/updated, when the parent entity is saved/updated (the reverse is true when inverse=true).

I also notice (updatable=false) on the userId, but setParameter() being invoked in updateUserCompany method. I think that's already been taken care of.